# Reusing HTML/CSS for another page but not identical

Tags: html, css, portfolio

I'm trying to reuse HTML from a previous page and write new content on a new page while still retaining the home button and footer for a portfolio. I copied over the HTML containing my home button and footer and used the same stylesheet. But upon opening up a new page with (mostly) the same content sans the hero and work section, the elements on my page look shifted over slightly to the right.

When I add the content from the landing page onto the new page, this problem goes away and the elements are flushed to the left like I want them. However, when I put in any content that does not contain the hero and work section from the landing page, the problem persists.

I've tried looking into not using margin and instead using positioning but am confused if this is the right direction I should go. I'll add the codepens to compare the two. Hopefully the difference is visible, as I really want to work on the actual content of my portfolio. I appreciate any advice.

[My landing page](https://codepen.io/manayam/pen/orVKbW):

```
<div class="container">
      <header>
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="index.html">Ryan M</a></h1>
      </header>

      <section class="hero">
        <p>Hi, <a href="about.html">I'm Ryan!</a></p>
        <p>
          I'm a recent graduate from UC San Diego, where I received a B.S. in
          Human-Computer Interaction. I am currently looking for work so feel
          free to <a href="#">send me an email!!</a>
        </p>
        <p class="social">
          <a href="#"
            >Resume</a
          >
          —
          <a href="#"
            >LinkedIn</a
          >
          —
          <a href="
                   #">Github</a>
        </p>
      </section>

      <section class="work">
        <h2>Work ↓</h2>
        <article>
          <h3 class="title">KOTX website design</h3>
          <h4 class="meta">Jan-Mar 2019</h4>
        </article>
      </section>
    </div>
```

[My new page](https://codepen.io/manayam/pen/pXYMyX) I'm trying to make

Comment: You can always override CSS property in the next page, using `<style>` tag, inline style or attach another CSS file.

Comment: They both look almost identical, but your second one has `max-width: 800px` on the container while your first one has `max-width: 900px`. I think that is the difference that makes it look like it is "shifted" to the right. Chrome and Firefox both have great Developer Consoles so you can hover over items to see how much space they take up, their margins etc.

Comment: My mistake, they're supposed to refer to the same stylesheet, so I updated each pen's CSS just now to have max-width: 900px. The problem of being shifted to the right still persists, however. And I only notice it when I take out some of the HTML like I do in the pen or add new elements that aren't the HTML previously.